# How to convert echo'ed voice to normal voice?

Tags: matlab, wav

I am working on MatLab and trying to improve myself.

I've currently converted some .wav file to echoed version with a function below

```
function [ ] = lab2echo(alpha,m )

fil=wavread('daffy.wav'); 
fil=transpose(fil);
fil2=[fil zeros(1,m)];
shifting_fil=[zeros(1,m) fil];
fil_echo=alpha*shifting_fil;
result=fil2+fil_echo;
sound(result);
end
```

and now I want to write a function that converts echoed voice to old version.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the cross correlation of the signal to itself. You should get two peaks. The difference between the peaks should be the echo delay.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is this operation enough for us to get original sound ? (the .wav file). And could you give me some clue with codes? I am completely new about it. Assignment wanted us to make it with echo effect. I did it and im trying to improve myself to reverse it back :)

Comment: Well, the way I would approach it is to use the run xcorr and graph it. You should visually see two peaks. Then run peak detection (find zero derivative locations, or some built in function) to find the locations. Then you can find some way to estimate which one is the echo and subtract it. You can write it back using wavwrite.

Comment: @user1700286: you _know_ the lag, and you _know_ the alpha. If the areas are not overlapping more than by 50%, then reconstruction should be perfect. Orig = new - alpha*new[-lag];

Comment: ı estimate it is all a few lines codes but ı havent found a way to deal with it. any recommended code lines ı can develop it ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not an easy way. But you can try to first to use xcorr to cross correlate the signal by itself to find the lag. Then you would have to estimate the contribution of the echo and subtract that.

There could be a value alpha, that minimizes the energy of `signal + alpha*delayed_signal`, where alpha>0.

Comment: Excuse me , a silly question but what do you mean by saying signal? I am not good at physics Im just a code-writer :P

Comment: signal in this case just means the matrix you are dealing with.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but majoring in DSP, I call those "voice thingies" signals.

Comment: Signal in DSP means a vector (or matrix) of numbers usually originated from a physical phenomenon. Signal in Signal Processing means a continuous waveform. An amplitude of pressure, voltage, current.